# How to install netstandard.dll v4.0.2.0.0.0

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I am trying to deploy a C# .Net application to our customer, which works fine on our site but does not work at our customer's site. The application complains with the following error:

`System.InvalidOperationException: There is an error in XML document (1, 2). ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.`

After further investigation I found out that on our server there is a file located at 
`c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\netstandard\v4.0_2.0.0.0__cc7b13ffcd2ddd51\netstandard.dll`

On our customer's site the same GAC_MSIL folder does not contain a netstandard folder.

What do I need to install on our customer's site to get this file added?

Regards,
Paddy

Comment: Require .net framework 4.7.2 or higher.

Comment: It seems this server is not maintained by Windows Update.  Bad idea, you'd better find out why before you upgrade the framework install yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Look like your C# development server and production server is not at same version of .NET framework.

Check your application, probably the latest developed in latest framework, then compare with this link below to find the most compatible , and upgrade your production server (or downgrade your development server) accordingly: [.NET Standard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard)